# How to do lookup on an aggregated collection in mongodb that is being grouped?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

For some reason, I can't retrieve the author name from another collection on my aggregate query.

```
db.getCollection('books').aggregate([
{
  $match: {
  authorId: { $nin: [ObjectId('5b9a008575c50f1e6b02b27b'), ObjectId('5ba0fb3275c50f1e6b02b2f5'), ObjectId('5bc058b6ae9a2a4d6df330b1')]},
  isBorrowed: { $in: [null, false] },
  status: 'ACTIVE',
},
},
{
    $lookup: {
     from: "authors",
     localField: "authorId", // key of author id in "books" collection
     foreignField: "_id", // key of author id in "authors" collection
     as: "bookAuthor",   
    }
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
        author: '$authorId',    
    },
    totalSalePrice: {
      $sum: '$sale.amount',
    },
  },
},
{
  $project: {
      author: '$_id.author',
      totalSalePrice: '$totalSalePrice',    
      authorName: '$bookAuthor.name', // I can't make this appear  
      _id: 0,
  },
},
{ $sort: { totalSalePrice: -1 } },
```

])

Any advice on where I had it wrong? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things that are missing here: you need [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to convert `bookAuthor` from an array into single object and then you need to add that object to your `$group` stage (so that it will be available in next stages), try:

```
db.getCollection('books').aggregate([
    {
    $match: {
        authorId: { $nin: [ObjectId('5b9a008575c50f1e6b02b27b'), ObjectId('5ba0fb3275c50f1e6b02b2f5'), ObjectId('5bc058b6ae9a2a4d6df330b1')]},
        isBorrowed: { $in: [null, false] },
        status: 'ACTIVE',
        },
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "authors",
            localField: "authorId", 
            foreignField: "_id", 
            as: "bookAuthor", // this will be an array   
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$bookAuthor"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                author: '$authorId',    
            },
            bookAuthor: { $first: "$bookAuthor" },
            totalSalePrice: {
                $sum: '$sale.amount',
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $project: {
            author: '$_id.author',
            totalSalePrice: '$totalSalePrice',    
            authorName: '$bookAuthor.name',  
            _id: 0,
        },
    },
    { $sort: { totalSalePrice: -1 } },
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have lost the `bookAuthor` field in the [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage.  You have to use [**`$first`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) accumulator to get it in the next [**`$project`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage.

```
{ "$group": {
  "_id": { "author": "$authorId" },
  "totalSalePrice": { "$sum": "$sale.amount" },
  "authorName": { "$first": "$bookAuthor" }
}},
{ "$project": {
  "author": "$_id.author",
  "totalSalePrice": "$totalSalePrice",    
  "authorName": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$bookAuthor.name", 0] }
  "_id": 0,
}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This approach also worked for me. :)